# randomize background music for pygame project

Tags: python-3.x, pygame

I am trying to shuffle my background music in this very basic space invaders game. I just want it to randomly play a song from a list of 5 songs whenever the game starts or is restarted(I haven't added a restart button yet)I'm not getting any errors in the terminal but there is also nothing playing.

```
# background music
play_list = []
play_list.append("./toonz/toon1.mp3")
play_list.append("./toonz/toon2.mp3")
play_list.append("./toonz/toon3.mp3")
play_list.append("./toonz/toon4.mp3")
play_list.append("./toonz/toon5.mp3")

def play_toonz(play_list):
    random.shuffle(play_list)
    pygame.mixer.music.load(play_list[songNumber])
    pygame.mixer.music.play(-1)

    for num, song in enumerate(play_list):
        if num == songNumber:
            continue
        mixer.music.queue(song)
```

Thinking I may have written the function incorrectly??

Comment: Where is songNumber set? Are you sure the paths to the song files are correct?

Comment: yes, I'm sure about the path to song files. but I'm not sure what you mean by "where is songNumber set" Should I write it as 'music.mixer.load(play_list[0:6])' instead?

Comment: @Mike67 is referring to the line `pygame.mixer.music.load(play_list[songNumber]`, in the included code. `songNumber` must be defined outside the scope of the `play_toonz()` function for the line to not generate an error.

Answer (score 2):

This code works for me:

```
import pygame
import random

pygame.mixer.init()

# background music
play_list = []
play_list.append(r"D:\MikeStuff\MP3\04-Zombie.mp3")
play_list.append(r"D:\MikeStuff\MP3\03 Invincible.mp3")
play_list.append(r"D:\MikeStuff\MP3\10. Kashmir.mp3")
play_list.append(r"D:\MikeStuff\MP3\11-fozzy-sos.mp3")
play_list.append(r"D:\MikeStuff\MP3\104-radiohead-creep.mp3")

songNumber = 1

def play_toonz(play_list):
    random.shuffle(play_list)
    pygame.mixer.music.load(play_list[songNumber])
    pygame.mixer.music.play(10)

    for num, song in enumerate(play_list):
        if num == songNumber:
            continue
        pygame.mixer.music.queue(song)
        
play_toonz(play_list)
input("Press Enter to Exit....")
```

Comment: I tried this out and I got this error:
```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 34, in <module>
    play_toonz(play_list)
  File "main.py", line 26, in play_toonz
    pygame.mixer.music.load(play_list[songNumber])
pygame.error: Failed loading libmpg123.dll: Attempt to access invalid address.
```

apparantly restarting the system can fix it.

also just curious what the 'r' is for in "play_list.append(r"path\to\file")"

Comment: The `r"..."` indicates that this is a raw string, so special characters will not be interpreted. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38742784/7675174) for some more information. To escape the backslashes, you would use `"D:\\MikeStuff\\MP3\\104-radiohead-creep.mp3"`